# SQL Server database backup size reduced dramatically

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL Server database which I backup every Sunday. Usually the `.bak` file's size is around 15 GB or more, but today I was shocked to see 710 MB.

I looked through the data and nothing is missing, there were no modifications made and I am the only one who has access to that database. I doubt this is a normal behaviour since I had this database running for over a year and the size of the backup was always increasing.

Any ideas why this happened?

Comment: Have you tried a restore to see if it contains everything? What size is the mdf file?

Comment: I restored it on local and nothing is missing. The .MDF file size of the restored backup is the same as the original one, yet the backup is still 14gb smaller

Comment: Yeah but what size is your MDF?

Comment: It's around 712mb

Comment: Then I would not worry about it. Maybe your log file was really large and has finally been shrunk. If you really care, restore an old backup and check the mdf and ldf file sizes. But seems you have no problem to solve here

Comment: That would be incredible, thank you

Comment: Maybe highly fragmented indexes which have now been rebuilt?

Comment: Yea, that's actually abnormal that your backups were 15 GB this whole time for a database that's only 712 MB big. I agree with Dale, your Transaction Log (.LDF) was probably really big (maybe Transaction Log backups weren't being taken until recently, and / or someone explicitly shrunk the Transaction Log) and now it's probably small again. I would recommend making sure if your database is set to Full Recovery Model that you are taking Transaction Log backups too. Or if you don't need point in time recovery (just weekly recovery is sufficient) then switch to Simple Recovery Model.

Comment: A large log file doesn't in itself mean that a full backup is big. You'd also need that a large portion of the log records are required to be in the full backup, for instance you have an open transaction that has been open for a long long time (covering a time span including modification worth these 14 GB data). Another option is that append was done to the same filename, and the file in fact included several backups.

Comment: Welcome to the DBA.SE community. To allow the community to provide you with an answer, you would have to provide more details. How are you backing up your database? Did you change your backup procedure? Did you maybe switch from a regular DIY backup using Maintenance Plans to Ola Hallengren's Maintenance Solution? Or did you go from DIY to something centralised like Simpana CommVault or Netbackup, etc.? Hit [edit] and provide more details in your question. Thanks.